# Artin Theorem 4.2.10 (b)

Tags: linear-algebra

The theorem mentioned in the question is listed in Artin's Algebra (page 106, $2^{nd}$ edition). Artin indicates that it can be proved by using row and column operations. I am wondering whether anyone could provide more hints, please? Thank you!

The theorem is quoted below.
"Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, there are invertible matrices $Q$ and $P$ such that $A'=Q^{-1}AP$ has the following form. Note that $I_r$ is the $r\times r$ identity matrix and $r$ is the rank of $A$, i.e. the dimension of column space of $A$." [image: Form of $A'$]

Update: I can understand that $Q$ or $Q^{-1}$ acts like elementary matrix or a product of a series of elementary matrices since it is on the left of $A$. Its effect is to make $A$ into a reduced echelon form, i.e., the identity matrix seen in the picture. However, I do not understand the role played by $P$. Any hint on this, please? Thank you!

Update 2: On a second thought, $Q$ alone cannot guarantee that we will get an identity matrix in the upper left corner. That is why $P$ is here. It is used to permute columns of $A$ so that the form in the theorem is insured. Since $P$ is again an elementary matrix, it is invertible, too.

Comment: Can you define $ A'$?

Comment: As the theorem states, $A'=Q^{-1}AP$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is any matrix, and $E$ is an elementary matrix of the appropriate size, then $EM$ is obtained from $M$ by performing an appropriate row operation on $M$. The same holds true for $ME$, except with respect to column, not row, operations.

Also, while you are correct in saying that by using an appropriate $Q$, you can bring $A$ to reduced echelon form, you are incorrect in concluding that $Q^{-1}A$ would necessarily look like the picture. Not all matrices in reduced echelon form look like that. For that you need column operations, hence $P$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is exactly what I thought while I was typing the update 2 above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand Gauss elimination, and upper echelon form. These matrices just carry out the procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can understand that $Q$ or $Q^{-1}$ acts like elementary matrix or a product of a series of elementary matrices since it is on the left of $A$. Its effect is to make $A$ into a reduced echelon form, i.e., the identity matrix seen in the picture. However, I do not understand the role played by $P$. Any hint on this, please? Thank you!